# why is printf() changing char* value

Tags: c, arguments, output

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char *line=NULL;

    while(1) {  

         line = readLine(inputFile); //return file pointer  
         if (line == NULL)
         break;
         processCommand(line);
    }
}


void processCommand(char *line){
    char *command = NULL,char *hallName = NULL,char *movieName=NULL;

    command = strtok(line," "); 

    if(command != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(command,"CREATEHALL") == 0) {
            hallName = strtok(NULL," ");
            movieName = strtok(NULL," ");
            if (hallName && movieName ) {
            //printf("MovieName: %s - HallName: %s\n",movieName,hallName);
                createHall(hallName,movieName);
         }
    }
}
void createHall(char* hallName,char* movieName) {
    printf("MovieName: %s - HallName: %s\n",movieName,hallName);
    //....
}
```

input.txt

CREATEHALL "Red-Hall" "StarDust"

CREATEHALL "Orange-Hall" "Last_Samurai"

CREATEHALL "Blue-Hall" "London_has_fallen"

output :

```
MovieName: "StarDust" - HallName: n

MovieName: "Last_Samurai" - HallName: n

MovieName: "London_has_fallen" - HallName:
```

when I delete command line which is `//printf("MovieName: %s - HallName: %s\n",movieName,hallName);`, the output is:

```
MovieName: - HallName:
MovieName: - HallName:▒
MovieName:"Last_Samurai" - HallName:"Orange-Hall"
MovieName:"Last_Samurai" - HallName:▒
MovieName:"London_has_fallen" - HallName:"Blue-Hall"
MovieName:"London_has_fallen" - HallName:▒
```

why printf which is in processCommands function changes the output of second printf. And why parameters don't passed correcty to createHall function.

This problem in Linux. There is no problem on windows.

Comment: Try initializing your variables like `char *command, *hallName, *movieName = "";`

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a small program that reproduces the issue? It's difficult to debug this code without knowing the context in which you are using it.

Comment: dont work.give an different outputs.

Comment: There must be more to the problem than what you show. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, not too hard for some simple string inputs.

Comment: @Balthamos i edited

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you are seeing. It works as expected with and without the extra printf statement.

Comment: Where come from the `readLine()` function in your code ? Because the returned char-pointer is maybe not  allocated inside (only a static array of char). Provide the source code or the library used.

Comment: These kinds of symptoms can be triggered by an [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The problem may be in the `readLine()` function: a local variable can be returned and this locale variable would not exist pass the end of the function `readLine()`. Or the additional space for the null-terminating character was not allocated and the string `line` is not well-formatted. As noticed by @JPiquard , it would be great to add the code of the `readLine()` function to your question.